# Large cardinal axioms and total recursive functions

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Are there known relationships between large cardinal axioms (say Mahlo or Woodin cardinals)
and total recursive functions (over the natural numbers) of the type:

$ZFC$ + large cardinal axiom $\vdash$ $f$ is a total recursive function,

but:

$ZFC \not\vdash$ $f$ is a total recursive function,

like this is known for different axiom systems of reverse mathematics, e.g.:

$ATR_0 \vdash$ the Goodstein function $G$ is total recursive,

but for the weaker system $ACA_0$ we have:

$ACA_0 \not\vdash$ the Goodstein function $G$ is total recursive.

Or, more generally asked, is there a relationship of the following kind:

If $LCA_1$ (large cardinal axiom 1) is stronger (wrt. consistency strength)
than $LCA_2$, then
$ZFC + LCA_1$ proves the totality of a recursive function $f$ which
grows faster than all recursive functions having totality proofs in
$ZFC + LCA_2$?

This question arises in investigations of the relationship between
learnability and provability, where provably total recursive functions
are used to schedule the learning process. A learning systems $\Lambda(\Sigma_1)$
using $\Sigma_1$ as a background theory is stronger than a learning system
$\Lambda(\Sigma_2)$, if $\Sigma_1$ allows totality proofs of recursive functions
growing faster than all recursive functions having totality proofs in $\Sigma_2$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\def\zfc{\mathrm{ZFC}}\def\lca{\mathrm{LCA}}$Yes. Normally, $\zfc+\lca_1$ proves not only the consistency of $\zfc+\lca_2$, but also the uniform reflection principle of $\zfc+\lca_2$ (at least for arithmetic formulas). In particular, the $\Sigma^0_1$-reflection principle is a $\Pi^0_2$ sentence provable in $\zfc+\lca_1$ but not in $\zfc+\lca_2$, and it can be expressed as the totality of the following function $f$: if $x$ is a code of a $\zfc+\lca_2$ proof of a $\Sigma^0_1$-sentence of the form $\exists u\,\theta(u)$ with $\theta\in\Delta^0_0$, let $f(x)$ be the minimal $u$ such that $\mathbb N\models\theta(u)$, otherwise $f(x)=0$.

To see that $f$ grows faster than any provably total recursive function of $\zfc+\lca_2$, let $g$ be such a function. We may assume without loss of generality that $g$ is increasing, and $g(x)=y$ has a $\Sigma^0_1$-definition $\exists w\,\lambda(x,y,w)$ which is provably total and (strictly) increasing in $\zfc+\lca_2$. Let $\theta(x,u)$ be the formula $\exists y,w\le u\,\lambda(2^x,y,w)$ (this is strictly speaking not $\Delta^0_0$, but this is easy to fix, I'll leave it like this to simplify the presentation). Then the formulas $\exists u\,\theta(\ulcorner n\urcorner,u)$ (where $\ulcorner n\urcorner$ denotes the binary numeral of $n$) have $\zfc+\lca_2$ proofs of Gödel number bounded by $p(n)$ for some polynomial $p$, but their smallest witnesses have magnitude at least $g(2^n)>g(p(n))$ for large enough $n$.

This argument shows that $f(m)>g(m)$ for infinitely many $m$. If we want this to hold for all sufficiently large $m$, it suffices to make the function increasing by using $f_2(x)=\max_{y\le x}f(y)$ instead of $f$.

Answer (score 7):

Since large cardinal axioms have arithmetic consequences not provable without them, the answer to your first question is yes. For example, let $f(n)=1$, provided that $n$ is not the Goedel code of a proof of a contradiction in  ZFC. Since large cardinals imply Con(ZFC), the theory ZFC+large cardinals proves that $f$ is total. But ZFC alone does not prove this (if consistent), since it is relatively consistent with ZFC that there are proofs of contradictions from ZFC.

For the more general question, suppose that the stronger theory not only proves the weaker theory, but also proves that whenever the weaker theory proves that a TM program computes a total function, then it really does. This is the situation for most large cardinals---for example the theory asserting that there is a weakly compact cardinal implies towers of smaller inaccessible cardinals, and so if a program is total inside such a $V_\kappa$, then it really is in $V$. Given this situation, let $f(n)$ be the function which first inspects all smaller $m\leq n$ to see which code proofs from the weaker theory that a certain function $g_m$ is total, and then let $f(n)$ be larger than all such $g_m(n)$. Our assumption on the stronger theory ensures that we can be confident that the computation of $g_m(n)$ converges, so $f(n)$ will be defined.

Comment: $f$ is the constant $1$ function, hence provably total in ZFC.

Comment: But the assertion that $f$ is like that is not provable in ZFC. We are refering to the functions by their TM programs.

Comment: The standard definition of a provably total recursive function is as follows: an $f\colon\omega\to\omega$ is a p.t.r.f. of a theory $T$ if there exists a $\Sigma^0_1$-formula $\phi(x,y)$ such that $T\vdash\forall x\,\exists!y\,\phi(x,y)$ and for every $n\in\omega$, $\mathbb N\models\phi(n,f(n))$. As you can see, the definition is purely extensional, it does not refer to particular TM.

Comment: Emil, you are the expert on this topic, so I defer to you. I consider using the TM program or the formula $\phi$ to be essentially equivalent. It seems that we should refer to the function by a particular $\phi$, though, since it may be the case that we can prove that one $\phi$ gives rise to a total function, but we can't prove it for another, even when the functions happen to be the same (in the standard model or with respect to a stronger theory). That is the situation of my first example, where the function happens to be the constant $1$ function, but ZFC does not prove it.

Comment: The gap here is indeed that the TM program and the formula are not essentially equivalent -- the TM program has some intensional content not present in the formula $f(n)=1$, as the 'proviso' on $n$ is externally invisible.  If denotational semantics was that easy, the whole theory would not exist...

Comment: TM programs and $\Sigma^0_1$ assertions are essentially equivalent. My formula $\phi(x,y)$  is ``$x$  is not the code of a proof of a contradiction and $y=1$'', which has the same intentional content of the program. The stronger theory proves $\forall n\exists!m\ \phi(n,m)$, but ZFC does not.

Comment: @Joel: Yes, different definitions of the same function may differ in their totality. Consider this as a feature. Essentially, the p.t.r.f. of a theory describe the $\Pi^0_2$ fragment of $T+\operatorname{Th}_{\Pi^0_1}(\mathbb N)$.

Comment: From the last paragraph of the question, it looks like the author may be interested in the $\Pi_2$ fragment of $T$ rather than that of $T+\mathrm{Th}_{\Pi_1}(\mathbb{N})$. In that case Joel's interpretation of provably total would be more appropriate than Emil's (for the purpose of answering the question). Perhaps the Joerg should clarify which he meant...

Comment: Emil, you are saying that when studying provable totality, one always throws the $\Pi^0_1$-theory of $\mathbb{N}$  into the theory? Why is this? The question seems to be perfectly sensible for theories not containing this extra stuff. 

Comment: You can study provably total algorithms (TM) if you wish, it’s perfectly sensible. I was simply pointing out that the (fairly traditional) definition of a provably total function does not distinguish different algorithms computing the same function. The rationale, I suppose, is that this characteristic of the theory is a set of combinatorial objects (functions), which can be studied with tools unrelated to logic. (The situation is akin to ordinals of a theory, there you also abstract away different definitions of the same ordinal.)...

Comment: ... There are other ways to study the $\Pi^0_1$ fragment of the theory, such as using consistency statements.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is also a pragmatic reason: provably total functions of a theory often have a simple description. For example, the provably total recursive functions of $T=I\Delta_0+\mathrm{EXP}$ are exactly the elementary function, i.e., functions computable in time $O(2_k^n)$ for some constant $k$. Every such function is computable by a TM provably total in $T$, but it is not true that every TM running in time $O(2_k^n)$ is provably total in $T$; that a particular TM halts in $2_k^n$ steps on any input is a $\Pi_1$ statement that may or may not be provable in $T$. ...

Comment: ... In contrast, there is no easy description of the set of all TM provably total in $T$. Generally speaking, one can only guarantee provable totality of TM that run in time $2_k^n$ for some syntactic reason, such as when the TM implements an explicit clock. However, there are also provably total TM that do not follow such an easily recognizable pattern (loosely speaking; the set of all provably total TM is of course r.e.).

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your quick and enlightening answers! Also the discussion about intensional and extensional definitions
raises an important point for further contemplation. As Francois has
correctly remarked, in my context the intensional view seems to be
appropriate, because I deal with programs executed on a universal
reference TM. It is fascinating, that these large cardinals, which
are directly concerned with unfathomable infinities, have such
interesting implications for effective objects.